# Java / Javascript : File Comparison line by line while ignoring certain section

Tags: java, file, comparison

**QUESTION : 
Is there a better way to compare two low size(100Kb) files, while selectively ignoring a certain portion of text. and report differences**

**Looking for default/existing java libraries or any windows native apps**

Below is scenario:

```
Expected file 1 located at D:\expected\FileA_61613.txt  
..Actual file 2 located at D:\actuals\FileA_61613.txt
```

**Content in expected File**

```
Some first line here


There may be whitespaces, line breaks, indentation and here is another line

Key        : SomeValue
Date       : 01/02/2012
Time       : 18:20
key2       : Value2
key3       : Value3
key4       : Value4
key5       : Value5

Some other text again to indicate that his is end of this file.
```

**Actual File to be compared:**

```
Some first line here


There may be whitespaces, line breaks, indentation and here is another line

Key        : SomeValue
Date       : 18/09/2013
Timestamp  : 15:10.345+10.00
key2       : Value2
key3       : Value3
key4       : Something Different
key5    : Value5


Some other text again to indicate that his is end of this file.
```

File 1 and 2 need to be compared line by line., **WITHOUT ignoring**
whitespaces, indentation, linebreaks

The comparison result should be like something below:
Line 8 - Expected Time, but actual Timestamp
Line 8 - Expected HH.mm, but actual HH.mm **.345+10.00**
Line 10 - Expected Value4, but actual Something different.
Line 11 - Expected indentation N spaces, but actual only X spaces
Line 13 - Expected a line break, but no linebreak present.

Below have also changed but **SHOULD BE IGNORED** :
Line 7 - Expected 01/02/2012, but actual 18/09/2013  (exactly and only the 10chars)
Line 8 - Expected 18:20 but actual :15:20 (exactly and only 5 chars should be ignored)
**Note** : The remaining **.345+10.00** should be reported

It is fine even if result just contains the line numbers and no analysis of why it failed.
But it should not just report a failure at line 8 and exit.
It should report all the changes, except for the excluded "date" and "time" values.

Some search results pointed to solutions using Perl.
But Looking for Java / Javascript solutions. 
The inputs to the solution would be full file path to both the files.

**My current work-around:**
Replace the text to be ignored with '#'.
When performing comparison, if we encounter #, do not consider as difference.
Below is my working code. But I need to know if i can use some default / existing libraries or functions to achieve this.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class fileComparison {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream(
                "D:\\expected\\FileA_61613.txt");
        FileInputStream fstream2 = new FileInputStream(
                "D:\\actuals\\FileA_61613.txt");
        DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(fstream1);
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));
        DataInputStream in2 = new DataInputStream(fstream2);
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in2));
        int lineNumber = 0;
        String strLine1 = null;
        String strLine2 = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        System.out.println(sb);
        boolean isIgnored = false;

        while (((strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null)
                && ((strLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null)) {
            lineNumber++;
            if (!strLine1.equals(strLine2)) {
                int strLine1Length = strLine1.length();
                int strLine2Length = strLine2.length();
                int maxIndex = Math.min(strLine1Length, strLine2Length);
                if (maxIndex == 0) {
                    sb.append("Mismatch at line " + lineNumber
                            + " all characters " + '\n');
                    break;
                }
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++) {
                    if (strLine1.charAt(i) == '#') {
                        isIgnored = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (strLine1.charAt(i) != strLine2.charAt(i)) {
                        isIgnored = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isIgnored) {
                    sb.append("Ignored line " + lineNumber + '\n');
                } else {
                    sb.append("Mismatch at line " + lineNumber + " at char "
                            + i + '\n');
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        br1.close();
        br2.close();

    }
}
```

I am able to get the output as :

```
Ignored line 7
Mismatch at line 8 at char 4
Mismatch at line 11 at char 13
Mismatch at line 12 at char 8
Mismatch at line 14 all characters
```

**However, when there are multiple differences in same line. I am not able to log them all, because i am comparing char by char and not word by word.

I did not prefer word by word comparison because, i thought it would not be possible to compare linebreaks, and whitespaces. Is my understanding right ?**

Comment: what you have done so far? It's better to show something you tried rather than asking us to do your job for free

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Those are two completely different languages.

Comment: I updated the thread with the code. I am trying to know if there is method / default api functionality or any concrete solution that can be used, instead of all the if, while and for loops that i used.

Comment: I am able to find out where is the difference in files, Then the next task is to ignore the selected text. When I try to implement that, It is skipping the next lines.

Comment: The topic is mentioned as [ on hold ], Is there something that i need to update or any other details. I am trying this using Java. 
Even if javascript is suggested as easy to do, i can try that.

Comment: Where's the question here?

Comment: Why do you need to write this from scratch, and doesn't a tool such as [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) or perhaps an existing Java library or tool suffice? Can the files be very big? (The problem may become hard in that case.) Why does the code need to be in Java or JavaScript?

Comment: @reinierpost
Files are not big. This code will be invoked by another tool. Considering its easy/native integration with java / javascript, the code can be either of them. I tried windows "cmp" but i get only the difference. I also need to ignore certain differences. my OS is windows, can i use diff to selectively ignore certain parts of the file.

Comment: diff you can have, if you install cygwin, I suppose

Comment: `diff` doesn't support selectively ignoring certain parts of the file; you'd have to preprocess the files for that. Who or what will use the output?

Comment: @reinierpost The output is just a result file which will be reviewed manually by users.

Comment: @Reddy the problem is handled using a workaround and with some compromises(not able to get proper reporting format, not able to get multiple differences within same line) . but i am searching if any users can suggest existing / standard ways to achieve it.

Comment: @Jesper This code will be invoked by another tool. Considering its easy/native integration with java / javascript, the code can be either of them.

Comment: If you are dealing with files on the user's filesystem, a visual diff tool such as [WinDiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDiff) or [TortoiseMerge](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseMerge.html) seems a good idea.They can't ignore certain sections, though ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` comes from this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strLine1.length(); i++) {
   if (strLine1.charAt(i) != strLine2.charAt(i)) {
       System.out.println("char not same at " + i);
   }   
}
```

When you scroll larger `String` strLine to an index, that is greater than the length of strLine2 (second file is smaller than the first) you get that exception. It comes, because strLine2 does not have values on those indexes when it is shorter.

Comment: yeah, i updated the code perform comparison based on maxIndex.